# PHP fsockopen script times out over ajax but completes almost instantly in commandline

Tags: php, ajax, fsockopen

I'm trying to make a webpage on another server where the status of my own server will be displayed.
I am using an AJAX-request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'status.php',
    data: {ip:address},
    success: function(data){
        //do stuff
    },
    dataType:'text'
});
```

to send the ip-address of the server to the status.php script, which looks like this:

```
if($_GET['ip']){
    $ip = $_GET['ip'];
    //var_dump($_GET['ip']); 
    $port = 64738;
    $up = fsockopen("tcp://$ip", $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);   
    if($up){   
        echo "success";   
    } 
    else{ 
        echo "failure";
}
```

I rewrote the script a bit like this:

```
$ip = "<ip_of_my_server>"; 
    $port = 64738;
    $up = fsockopen("tcp://$ip", $port, $errno, $errstr, 5);   
    if($up){   
        echo "success";   
    } 
    else{ 
        echo "failure";
    }
```

so I can use it from the command line, for testing purposes.

This second script works perfectly and almost instantly from the command line and outputs "success".

But with the AJAX request, the first and second script will both give errornr. 110 (connection timed out) for the fsockopen output after 30 seconds and thus output "failure".

What could be reason?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: firewall rules? You're testing on windows?

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Nothing is blocked on both servers for that particular port as far as I can see. Also sites like http://www.yougetsignal.com/ and nmap confirm that the port is open.

Both servers are running Linux, the testing with AJAX is by going to the webpage which sends it (on Google Chrome on Windows).

Comment: The problem's symptom is something that blocks the outgoing connection. In windows (dev env) I had a similar problem because the firewall blocks all outgoing connection for every process. Maybe the php (cli) is allowed but the webserver is not. That's all I have in my mind :-). Waiting for other possibilities.